# WordPress: add shortcode into a concatenate variable

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to make this work but it's not working. What's wrong with this piece of code?

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'addslider_hook' );
function addslider_hook ( $content ) {

    if ( is_page('outsourced') ) {
        $slide = '[rev_slider outsourced]';
        $hook_slide = do_shortcode( $slide );

        $content .= "<div class='page-slider'>";
        $content .= $hook_slide;
        $content .= "</div>";
    } 
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a extra } at the bottom of the code.You can try this

```
if ( is_page('outsourced') ) {      
    $content .= "<div class='page-slider'>";
    $content .= do_shortcode('[rev_slider outsourced]');
    $content .= "</div>";
    echo $content;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, this piece of code is inside a function that extra } is the closing parenthesis of a function. Accidentally included. I update the code.

Comment: Where did you put this code actually ? On page template ?

Comment: I updated the code. It's in functions.php file. Basically i want to add a slider at the bottom of some specific page.

Comment: So this one should have ` $content .= "<div class='page-slider'>";` a dot(.) after `$content`.